# How to get keys and values of .json file which is generated by parser dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, parsing, json.net

We have following scenario,

We need to parse resumes of candidates and i am using below parser to parse resume in `Json` format, right.

https://github.com/antonydeepak/ResumeParser

and Json files which i get are in valid format as i checked them in online `jsonviewer`, but it is cleared that each resume is in different format. so each time parser introduced new pair of `Keys` ,

**Example 1.**

[image]

**Example 2.**

[image]

Above two formats are of two different resumes and so on...

so now i need to iterate through every `key` and `value` that are dynamically generated.

as for as i did to get `JObject` and `JArray` at level 0, now i need to iterate through each `JObject` and `JArray` to get its values.

I used `Json.net` to get them

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\abc.json");
var d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(text);
```

and it showed me data as

[image]

abc.json has `JObjects` and `JArray`, so now i need to iterate through each and every line and need to get every `key` and `value` from parsed `json` file and load it to `datatable` and tried it using google , but it missed some of keys and values.

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\antony_thomas.json");
var d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(text);

            foreach (var item in d)
            {
                var key = "";
                var val = item.Value;

                if (val is JObject)
                {
                    dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Convert.ToString(val));
                    foreach (var ite in dynObj)
                    {
                        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                        string jsonvalue = Convert.ToString(ite).Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Replace("\"", "");
                        string jkey = jsonvalue.Split(':')[0];
                        string jval = jsonvalue.Split(':')[1];
                        row["Key"] = jkey;
                        row["Value"] = jval;
                        dt.Rows.Add(row);
                    }


                   // key = item.Key;
                }

                if (val is JArray)
                {
                    //key = item.Key;
                    foreach (var it in val)
                    {
                        // var newkey=
                        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                        string jsonvalue = Convert.ToString(it).Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Replace("\"", "");
                        //Convert.ToString(test);
                        string jkey = jsonvalue.Split(':')[0];
                        string jval = jsonvalue.Split(':')[1];
                        row["Key"] = jkey;
                        row["Value"] = jval;
                        dt.Rows.Add(row);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I am using `asp.net` , `C#`, `Json.net` , if anyone have any idea so please guide me how can i get my desired result..

Comment: are you looking to convert json file to Datatable?

Comment: @Aravind, i need  it in digital format either datatable or something else, thats why i share it to you expert people. give me right way to extract my data.

Comment: is there any defined format? or a random one?

Comment: @Aravind, this is actual problem, we don't have defined format. parser generate it dynamically and each time keys are different.

Comment: if there is json array for a particular key then it is complex to do!! the way for reading the format can be modified??

Comment: @Aravind,Most of keys have json arrays to show data. i know its complex but may be sharing knowledge will put us on right path. already it took 1 week of me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128123/discussion-between-aravind-and-waqas).

Comment: i dont think that keys are always different. they are always the same, they are just not always included. if the parser finds work_experience for example, its key is always work_experience.... you might need to go through the source code and check all the occurrences of `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` in https://github.com/antonydeepak/ResumeParser/blob/master/ResumeTransducer/src/code4goal/antony/resumeparser/ResumeParserProgram.java this way you can find out what members are available

Comment: @nozzleman, practically i checked its keys, some of keys are changed because it includes probability due to not fixed resume format. I tried some tricks and it shows some appropriate data that i want. let me give some time to test on different resumes then i will update my question including answer to share knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I used this code recently to traverse an arbitrary JSON string.
Each element is dumped with a row of dots at the beginning indicating its level in the hierarchy.
You could modify it to output to a `DataTable` as you walk through an `JArray` for example.

```
public static void JsonFileDump(string path)
{
    //Parse the data
    string jsonStr = File.ReadAllText(path);
    JToken token = JToken.Parse(jsonStr);   // get parent token
    JsonTokenDump(token);
}

public static void JsonTokenDump(JToken node, int lvl = 0, string nodeName = null)
{
    if (nodeName != null)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}Node Name={1}, Type={2}", new string('.', lvl), nodeName, node.Type);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("{0}Node Type={1}", new string('.', lvl), node.Type);


    if (node.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    {
        foreach (JProperty child in node.Children<JProperty>())
        {
            JsonTokenDump(child.Value, lvl + 1, child.Name);
        }
    }
    else if (node.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    {
        foreach (JToken child in node.Children())
        {
            JsonTokenDump(child, lvl + 1);
        }
    }
}
```